# Why is there a $m-1$ when approximating a lower bound of a function through summation or integral?

Tags: calculus, functions, summation, upper-lower-bounds

For a monotonically increasing f(x), why does the summation below, on the left hand side, always approximate the lower bound of the summation on the right hand side?

$\int_{k=m-1}^n f(k) \leq \sum_{k=m}^n f(k)$

If $f(x)=k$, $m=2$, and for $n\geq 2$ then the left hand summation is no longer a lower bound, which contradicts the above.

This formula sheet from a class suggests the left hand side would be a lower bound: https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2018/cmsc351-01XX02XX/files/info.pdf

EDIT: I understand that I'm going wrong somewhere but I don't know where. The purpose of my comments is to demonstrate my reasoning for why I think there's a contradiction so that others can point out where my reasoning is incorrect. Thanks

EDIT 2: I've changed the summation symbol to an integral symbol to avoid confusion. It's worth nothing the results would be the same since the functions are called on integers (discrete intervals).

EDIT 3: The result is not the same with the change from a summation to integral because the $n$ on the left hand side is not included in the summation (so same as summation $m-1$ to $n-1$). Thanks Ross!

Comment: Wouldn't the left hand side with $f(x)=k$ be $(n-(m-1))k=(n-m+1)k$ and the right hand side be $(n-m)k$? EDIT: The comment I was responding to got deleted.

Comment: Your latest edit has  made my answer inappropriate.  The original version had two sums.  Now there is not a left hand sum for my comments to apply to.  The statement you now make is correct for $f$ increasing as the Riemann sum takes the right side of each interval.

Comment: I've understood my mistake, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The upper limit on the left should be $n-1$.  The integral you are approximating is from $m-1$ to $n$.  You have ends and break points at $m-1,m,m+1,m+2\ldots n-1,n$.  Using the left side takes the value of $f(x)$ from the left hand end of each interval while the right side takes the value of $f(x)$ from the right hand side of each interval.  As $f(x)$ is increasing, the right side will be larger.  The true integral will be between the two values.

Your formula sheet gives for $f(x)$ increasing
$$\int_{m-1}^nf(x)dx \le \sum_{k=m}^nf(k)\le \int_{m}^{n+1}f(x)dx$$
When you try to bound the left integral by a sum you need to make the limits on the integral match.  If you shift the limits on the right integral down by $1$ you get the left integral.  The lower bound sum then has to have both its limits decreased by $1$, giving the correct formula 
$$\sum_{k=m-1}^{n-1}f(k) \le \int_{m-1}^nf(x)dx \le \sum_{k=m}^nf(k)$$
This shows the upper limit on the left sum should be $n-1$.  The easiest way to see the problem is to use $f(x)=1$.  Your left sum is then $n-m+1$ and your right sum is $n-m$.  The integral is also $n-m$.  You are adding one too many terms on the left.

Comment: This contradicts the formula sheet here: https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2018/cmsc351-01XX02XX/files/info.pdf and here: http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap03.htm (CTRL + F "approximation by integrals". Both use $m-1$ for the lower bound and do not use $n-1$ for the upper bound.

Comment: You want to sum the same number of terms on both sides.  I have usually seen the right starting at $m$ going to $n-1$  and the left starting at $m+1$ going to $n$.  The logic is the same.  Just take $f(x)=1$ to see that you need the number of terms to match.

Comment: The formula sheet you linked in the question has the sum bounded by integrals, but the idea is the same.  The range of the integrals is $n-m+1$ and the number of terms in the sum is $n-m+1$

Comment: How is the number of terms the same if one side is going from $m-1$ to $n$ and the other side is going from $m$ to $n$? The left hand side has 1 more term in addition to all the terms of the right hand side. Thus, the left hand side must be larger whenever $m \geq 2$ and $n \geq 2$.

Comment: For example, if $f(x)=x$, $m=2$ and $n=3$ then $\sum_{x=1}^{3} x \leq \sum_{x=2}^{3} x $ does not hold true (because 1 + 2 + 3 is greater than 2 + 3)

Comment: Your next to last comment is exactly my point.  The number of terms is not the same and that is why one of the limits must be corrected.  You can fix the upper limit on the left or the lower one on the right.

Comment: I agree with that but this contradicts the formula sheets from classes at separate universities (linked in first comment to your answer). I think it's unlikely two professors at separate universities would make the same mistake on their formula sheets without it going unnoticed by several students.

Comment: It looks like one of the ones in your comment is the same as the one in the question.  It only bounds the sum by integrals and has the correct number of terms to match the length of the interval.  The other one you linked is correct.  The left goes from $m$ to $n+1$, the right from $m-1$ to $n$.  It is for decreasing functions which explains the swap.

Comment: Both links state the same regarding upper and lower bounds. The $m$ to $n+1$ is the lower bound and the $m-1$ to $n$ is the upper bound for the monotonically decreasing. Yes, both upper and lower bounds have the same number of terms but they do not have the same number of terms as the function which we're determining the upper and lower bounds for.

Comment: The length of the interval is from $m$ to $n+1$ or $m-1$ to $n$, which is a length of $n-m+1$.  The sum runs from $m$ to $n$ inclusive, which is $n-m+1$ terms.  They have to match and do.  I think you have a fencepost error.